# Issue with ternary operator syntax in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, syntax, ternary-operator

I'm trying to use a ternary operator in vb.net but to determine what to append to a string but I am having issues with syntax...

Why does line three give an error on **== generates expression expected error**

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
Dim bln As Boolean
bln == true ? sb.append("True") : sb.Append("False")
' this also doesn't work
bln ? sb.append("True") : sb.Append("False")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ternary operator in VB.NET is used like this:

```
If(<Test Statement>, <Result if True>, <Result if False>)
```

So you could do this:

```
sb.Append(If(bln, "True", "False"))
```

But this would be a better way to accomplish what you need:

```
sb.Append(CStr(bln))
```

Answer (score 2):

On C based languages it use to be like:

```
String name = (person == null) ? "" : person.Name;
```

But in VB.Net it is like:

```
Dim name As String = If(person Is Nothing, "", person.Name)
```